# what is php action?

Tags: php

What is PHP action? Is there anything called as PHP action? I tried to google it and look up different web forums but was not able to find anything related to this. A recruiter had sent me an email where he wanted someone with skills/experience in "PHP action". Just curious.

Comment: "PHP Action" is what you get when you go to a geeky nightclub wearing a nametag that says *Hello, My Name Is Zend*.

Comment: Lol! I just called him up and he told me that he meant "PHP auction" and left out the "U" instead :)

Comment: @Justin If that was an answer, I'd vote on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action is a term used throughout the Symfony Framework 1.x, perhaps he was referring to that. They are basically page controllers. Few examples:

```
// apps/myApp/modules/myModule/actions/actions.class.php

public function executeIndex() {} 
public function executeResult() {}
```

Comment: But then the requirement would read "PHP / Symfony", wouldn't it? It seems to make little sense in a technology requirements list

Comment: Have you dealt with a tech recruiter before? Great people but not very tech savvy.

Comment: I've never read a job description/requirements list that was accurate.

Comment: @Digital I know. Still, this looks like a stretch. Well, you never know.

Comment: This was my first guess too. Maybe someone using symfony tried explaining something to him, mentioned actions and templates or something, then an inside buzz word was born. "This project needs faster php actions!"

Answer (score 2):

If it stood on its own like that, my guess is the recruiter doesn't know what he's talking about. Maybe it was a copy+pasting error from "Actionscript" or something.

"PHP Action" is not a defined term. At least not one I have ever heard of.

My tendency would be to respond anyway, and then sort the details out later when getting interviewed by the actual employer.

Answer (score 0):

he Action attribute is crucial. It means, "Where do you want the form sent?". If you miss it out, your form won't get sent anywhere. You can send the form data to another PHP script, the same PHP script, an email address, a CGI script, or any other form of script.

In PHP, a popular technique is to send the script to the same page that the form is on – send it to itself, in other words. We'll use that technique first, but you'll see both techniques in action.

So we're going to be sending the form data to exactly the same page as the one we have loaded – to itself. We'll put some PHP on the page to handle the form data. But for now, save your work again and then click your submit button. You won't see anything different, but you shouldn't see any error message either!
Once your script has an Action attribute set, you can then Submit it. Which we'll see in the next part.

Comment: Not to mention that this was answered six years ago